SocketIO URL stops working when there are more than 1 AWS EC2 instances
I have AWS EC2 instance and on that server I have my static Angular web site, NodeJS server. Server has 2 routes one for API (/api) and one for socket (/socket) that are managed using nginx. There is a load balancer and distributes the traffic. This all works fine with 1 instance, but when the server scales either manually or through autoscaling only the /socket rout is not reachable and client cannot establish socket connection but everything else works fine.
Here is my nginx route setup.
        location /api {
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
        }

        location /socket {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location / {
                root /home/ubuntu/angular-website-folder-location;
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

My assumption is that it is either load balancer or nginx. I am happy to update question with more information. I don't know what else to put.

How do you know the socket route is not reachable? What is the specific error message you get? If this all works with 1 instance behind the load balancer, but not 2, then I fail to see how the load balancer would be blocking the socket connection. It sounds like either the new instance that is added isn't starting up correctly or isn't allowing socket connections for some reason, or you have a some sort of login/session issue with multiple instances (which is very common) that might be solved by enabling sticky sessions on the target group.

I get error in console with 400 bad request to url and warning message Websocket is closed before connection can be established.
As I said everything else works fine except this. Since API and Socket are on the same nodejs server I know it’s started and working.
I am not too familiar with sticky sessions. I’ll do little research

In order to implement socket communication through load balancer, you would have to implement sticky session - https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html

Thank you all for pointing in the right direction. We resolved the issue by enabling sticky session and adding redis adapter. If somebody wants to write the answer I am happy to give a credit, otherwise I will post our solution next week
